# MyDocuments twice in users folder

Tags: windows-7

My laptop (Win7 PRO SP1) picked up a second instance of 'My Documents' in C:\Users\user_name.

A) is this normal?

B) if not, what to do about it?

The first one seems to be a link, and double clicking it gives an error pop-up 'Location is not available. C:\Users\gottsch\My Documents is not accessible. Access denied.'. Double click on the other instance performs the expected behavior.
Thanks,
Gert

[image]

Comment: One is an actual folder the other is a shortcut.  Just delete the shortcut.  It is not normal.

Comment: It is worth pointing out.  Your Documents and Settings clearly has a permission problem.  I am going to guess your original user profile became corrupt, based on the fact My Documents was created today, and a new profile directory was created.